# JQueryUI Modal Dialog; Using with Dynamic Images

Tags: php, jquery-ui, dynamic, modal-dialog

I am using the jQueryUI dialog modal like this:

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
    <img src="#" alt="Pictures" />
</div>
```

I have a PHP **foreach** loop that displays three image icons at any given moment. The image urls are in a MySQL database. The images themselves are contained inside anchor tags, and shown as a thumbnail. The `<a>` contains a class called "theLink". jQuery knows to open up the dialog when you click on "theLink" (in essence, clicking on the pic).

My hope is to allow the image to be shown much larger than a thumbnail by clicking on it.  And then it will dynamically transfer the image link to the modal dialog where it will be shown.  So again, one modal dialog div (as seen above) just under the `<body>` tag. This is what I am looking for:

When you click on "theLink" it will take the PHP generated image link from the img and use it to replace the "#" in the modal div.

```
<a> <img src="PHP GENERATED" /> </a>
```

Comment: Can you add more of the HTML, CSS and JavaScript/jQuery that you are having a problem with please? I'm struggling to understand what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer by getting jQuery basics down.

I had to create a class called ImageLink in the image that is php generated.  I had to use a class, not an ID because this class would be repeated three times as I have three thumbnails displayed at a time.

Keyword 'this' was important so I can point to the specific imageLink class.

```
  <a><img src="PHP GENERATED" class="imageLink" /></a>
```

Then, in jQuery:

```
    var realImage = $(this).find('.imageLink').attr("src");
    $('#popUpImage').attr('src', realImage);
    $('#dialog-modal').dialog('open');
```